# Added property "Show icon to toggle password visibility" not working in Install4J

Tags: install4j

I'm using Install4J version 6.1.6. and I added to a password field the property:

- "Show icon to toggle password visibility".
  `property="eyeVisible" , true`

I would like to see the password when clicking this icon.

Unfortunately this property not working when running the deployment. Do I need to add another property in order to work?

Answer (score 0):

The password is shown while you hold the mouse pressed on the "eye" icon, it does not permanently switch the password to be visible.

[image]

Comment: Thank you . The icon doesn’t exists... that’s my issue .

Comment: It works for me, please verify with the current version. I have added a screen shot of how it looks like.